# Query Google Maps API results from Google My Business Listings

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-my-business-api

my company manages our branch location listings in Google maps using Google My Business. Is there a way in the Google Maps API to display *only* the listings from my Google My Business listings?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such functionality in public Google Maps APIs.

However, there is Google My Business API that allows to retrieve all locations related to your account.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/location-data#list_all_locations

You can combine Google My Business API with Google Maps APIs when it's convenient.